# Spring MVC: where can i get line-by-line explanation of the way Spring MVC process HTTP request?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Dispatcher servlet invokes a handler (a controller) based on handler mappings and then the matching controller delegates a service object to perform business logic and then returns back the created model to dispatcher servlet and then dispatcher servlet decides which view to pass model to ... blah blah.
my question is whether there is any web page or book that explain about all these things. for example,

- what method does dispatcher servlet invoke on handler adaptor in order to invoke the matching controller?
- what method does dispatcher servlet invoke on view interface in order to build a view?
- etc.

Any web page would be awesome.

Comment: could someone explain why i gaved downvotes in detail? I don't really know why.

Comment: Read Spring in practice by wheeler, and documents from spring website. Reason for downvotes **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."**

Comment: Spring source code is freely available. High quality IDEs with debuggers are freely available. Why don't you download the Spring MVC source code, run your project, and step through it?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer these links :
[Spring MVC Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)
[Spring MVC Hello World](http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-mvc-hello-world/)